# ¿ Cómo asignar roles de usuarios en nodejs & mongodb?

Tags: nodejs, express, users-roles

Tengo creado un modelo de usuarios con usuario y contraseña, y un campo boleano para definir si el usuario es admin o no, pero lo que quiero poder hacer para gestionar esto mejor, es definir unos roles de usuario en su creación, por ejemplo "administrador", "editor", "manager", "lector" ... etc.

El Schema del modelo "User" es este:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var userSchema = new Schema({
 username: { type: String },
 password: { type: String },
 admin: { type: Boolean }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Después poder gestionar qué peticiones pueden hacer a la API que estoy creando según que rol de usuario tenga asignado el que haga la petición, lo mismo en la parte de frontend. Pero es que no tengo idea de cómo poder incluir o gestionar los roles de usuario y poder aplicarlos después, he buscado en manuales etc ... pero no encuentro nada concreto respecto a esto.

Gracias

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia. Depende en su mayoría de cual framework escogiste para implementar tu aplicación ya que frameworks de node hay muchos y la estrategia puede no ser siempre la misma.

Comment: perdón se me olvidó mencionar que utilizo express como framework de nodejs

Comment: La pregunta sigue siendo amplia ya que express puede usar unos cuantos módulos para ayudarte a conseguir lo que buscas. Recuerda que cuando una petición llega a tu servidor *debería* pasar por una fase llamada autenticación que por lo general cuando es satisfactoria asigna al objeto `req` una propiedad `user` con la información de tu usuario autenticado. Existen muchos módulos que te permiten lograr eso pero depende en gran medida de como es el mecanismo de autenticación de tu servidor (cookies, oauth, openid, etc).

Comment: La autentificación la estoy realizando con Passport y jwt para la creación del token.

Comment: Deberías incluir el código relevante de esa parte en tu pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo crearía el modelo de la siguiente forma:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
                             username: { type: String },
                             password: { type: String },
                             admin: { type: String,
                                      enum: ['Administrador','Editor','Manager,'Lector']
                                    }
                           });
```

Después, en cada endpoint colocaría un middleware que compruebe que el usuario que pretende acceder a ese endpoint puede hacerlo:

```
router.get('/',function(req,res,next){
                   // OBTENER ROL DEL USUARIO QUE PRETENDE ACCEDER
                   // SI EL USUARIO TIENE EL ROL NECESARIO
                       next();
                   // SI NO
                      let error = new Error("No autorizado");
                      next(error);
               }, function(req,res,next){

                    // HACER LO QUE PROCEDA EN EL ENDPOINT

                  }
```

Comment: Mil gracias por la ayuda, justo es lo que hice, pero me alegra ver que fue una buena opción.

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que deberías guardar en la session de passport el nivel del perfil autenticado y preguntar por dicho role a la hora de mandar una respuesta u otra.

Básicamente debes usar el modulo express-session, es un modulo muy chulo para el manejo de cookies y sesiones seguras, cuando haces login guardas en el servidor (en la session) el dato que tu necesitas y ya solo es preguntar por el para como te comentaba antes enviar al response una cosa u otra (dependiendo del role) cuando el usuario haga logout destruyes la session.

Aqui la documentación https://github.com/expressjs/session

Otra opción es usar algún modulo tipo mongoose-role pero sin haberlo usado nunca me da la sensación que por cada petición busca en bbdd si tienes autorización con la correspondiente carga que supondría.

Comment: Hola @Rulogarcillan. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Gracias por contribuir. ¿Podrías agregar más información a tu respuesta, de modo que sea de mayor utilidad para futuros lectores?